# Including PHP files doesn't work outside of Localhost

Tags: widgets

I have a bunch of widgets that I load from php files, like so: 
I added a PHP CODE widget and inside wrote:

```
<?php
include '/wp-content/themes/myTheme/parts/block1.php';
?>
```

This worked well on my localhost, but for some reason it stopped working 
when I uploaded that website online (and switched the home and site_url of course).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to load a PHP file in the theme directory is to use the locate_template function.

```
<?php locate_template(array('parts/block1.php'),true,false); ?>
```

The true makes it automatically require it. The false makes it not require_once it.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems.  You may want to use the built in WordPress constants:

```
<?php
include WP_CONTENT_URL.'/themes/myTheme/parts/block1.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I included the file product-menu.php by using

```
<?php get_template_part( 'product-menu'); ?>
```

and I thought I'd put a code into the top of it to mark it as being the product menu - but turns out that I didn't